# How to open a form in modal from controller while redirect

Tags: forms, ajax, redirection, modal-dialogs

I can open a form in modal when click on a link (and there are lot of examples in the net as well).

What I like to do:
When some one go to a url in browser or redirect to a url, it will open a dialog/modal form.

-I have defined a controller for a url
-In the controller function I placed the code like this:

```
  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  $title = $this->t('Confirmation');
  $form = $this->formBuilder->getForm('Drupal\example\Form\MyModalForm', $entity);
  $response->addCommand(new OpenModalDialogCommand($title, $form, ['width' => '800']));
```

But its not opening the Modal Form, rather showing json code in a textarea. Surely dialog box library might be missing. So I added the library:

```
    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';
```

in the form, in the page preprocess, etc. But none is working.

It is showing json code like this (example)

```
[{"command":"openDialog","selector":"#drupal-modal","settings":null,"data":"Something to show","dialogOptions":{"width":"800","modal":true,"title":"Confirmation"}}]
```

Can anyone help me, on how to open the dialog/modal when visiting the url?

Comment: You need client-side javascript to process the ajax commands. See for example https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/299270/how-do-i-display-a-modal-dialog-on-page-load-with-working-title-and-dialog-opti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach suggested by @4k4 might be correct, I did not test
[How do I display a modal dialog on page load, with working title and dialog options, using OpenModalDialogCommand?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/299270/how-do-i-display-a-modal-dialog-on-page-load-with-working-title-and-dialog-opti)

What I did:
Displayed a link and using JavaScript on load trigger the link, which eventually open the modal dialog.

This is not a good solution for me.