# how to create modal on load of page

Tags: 10

The following code is not working for me.

```php
$config = \Drupal::config('popup.settings');
$title = $this->t('Fnord');
$content = [
  '#type' => 'processed_text',
  '#text' => $config->get('content')['value'],
  '#format' => $config->get('content')['format'],
 ];
$options = [
  'dialogClass' => 'popup-dialog-class',
  'width' => '75%',
];

$response = new AjaxResponse();
$response->addCommand(new OpenModalDialogCommand($title, $content, $options));

return $response;
```

```js
(function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var ajaxSettings = {
     url: '/popup/modal'
    };
    var myAjaxObject = Drupal.ajax(ajaxSettings);
    myAjaxObject.execute();
  }); 
})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

I wrote the code basing on [How do I display a modal dialog on page load, with working title and dialog options, using OpenModalDialogCommand?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/299270/how-do-i-display-a-modal-dialog-on-page-load-with-working-title-and-dialog-opti)

It is giving me this JSON response but not opening the modal. Could you please help me with this?

```json
[{"command":"openDialog","selector":"#drupal-modal","settings":null,"data":"","dialogOptions":{"dialogClass":"popup-dialog-class","width":"75%","modal":true,"title":"Fnord"}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a custom module

1. In the module you have controller that provides a main page page where you want to show the modal popup (on page load).
2. You also need to add a custom library (in a <my_module>.libraries.yml) file. That library will point to a jasvascript file where you have javascript code mentioned above:

```
my_modal:
  js:
    js/script.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/drupalSettings
```

3. To load the javascript code on the main page, you need to attach the library in the controller build array:

```
$build['#attached']['library'][] = 'my_module/my_modal';
```

4. The content of the modal will provided by the ajax callback with the php code snipet showed above.
   Here, as I said in my previous comment, you need to attach the core dialog ajax library:

```
$attachments['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';
$response->setAttachments($attachments);
```

Or, you can add it as a dependency in the custom library.

5. Last:  you need to provide the routing with the paths to main page and to ajax callback.

Comment: Thanks for responding but still I am getting the below response but not modal.  could you please tell me more on this so, I can check it rom my end "config object with the name popup.settings with correct structure. "

Comment: I added more details to my previous answer.